# Diference between two code of: constant pointer to a constant integer initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

What is the difference between these two codes?

1.

```
const int ic = 2;
const int* const p3;
p3 = &ic;
```

2.

```
const int ic = 2;
const int* const p3 = &ic;
```

1 doesn't compile. 2 does compile. To me, it looks the same as we are just assigning the memory adress of constant integer to a constant pointer pointing to the constant integer. I am guessing it is something to do with initialization or convention in C++.

Edit:  `error: assignment of read-only variable 'p3'` on the first one. I don't see why it is read-only when it is not even initialized. As per the const rule, values cannot be changed once initialized but this one is not even initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bit confusing at first. Here you have a `const` pointer to a `const int`, so the variable itself (the pointer) is `const`. Everything marked `const` has to be initialized in C++ at construction (creation). In your first snippet, you leave it un-initialized,

```
const int* const p3; // const pointer un-initialized, error here
```

so that's why the error. It's similar to trying

```
const int i; // won't compile
i = 42;
```

You cannot just define a `const` without initializing it.

Comment: Does it mean that p3 is pointing to some arbitrary location when unitialized?

Comment: @NimitPatel No, it doesn't mean that. The compiler will simply not accept the code. Any `const` has to be initialized at creation (as most likely the compiler will put the value in a different area of the executable, e.g. a read-only area).